# could not load javascript for contentscript

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

i am developing extension for google chrome. i am trying to load css file.if the css file is in root directory of extension then it loaded fine. but if i put css in /css folder then try to load css then it gives error could not load javascript for contentscript

```
{
"name": "test",
"version": "1.0",
"manifest_version": 2,
"description": "This is test",
"background":{"scripts":["background.js"]},
"permissions": 
 [
  "http://*/*",
  "https://*/*",
  "file://*"
 ],
"content_scripts":
 [
  {
 "matches":["*://mail.google.com/*"],
 "css":["mystyle.css", "default.css","style.css"],
 "js":["jquery.js","myscript.js","DOMAlert.js","css/core.js"]
  }
 ]
}
```

i am new at developing extension so please help what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to be having the same issue. I managed to achieve this when I added a script that is external to my plugin. Check all of your js scripts to have exact spelling and case. It only complains about javascript if there is a permissions issue or the file does not exist.